# Closed form of series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

writing these in closed forms. Firstly i want to know if there is a specific way to solve these and if yes what should i look at before i approach these problems.

$$x+\sum^{\infty}_{k=3}(\frac{(-1)x^{2k}}{2k(2k-1)}$$
and
$$\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}(\frac{(-1)x^{2k+1}}{2k(2k+1)}$$
looks like sin and cos closed forms but i can't bring them to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the two series are $$x+\sum_{k\geq3}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}x^{2k}}{2k\left(2k-1\right)},\,\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}x^{2k+1}}{2k\left(2k+1\right)}
 $$ we have, by partial fractions, $$x+\sum_{k\geq3}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}x^{2k}}{2k\left(2k-1\right)}=x+\frac{x^{2}}{2}-\frac{x^{4}}{12}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k+1}x^{2k}}{k}+\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}x^{2k}}{2k-1}=
 $$ $$=x+\frac{x^{2}}{2}-\frac{x^{4}}{12}+\frac{1}{2}\log\left(1+x^{2}\right)-2x\tan^{-1}\left(x\right)
 $$ by Taylor expansion of $\log\left(1+x\right),\ \tan^{-1}\left(x\right)
 $ (assuming also $\left|x\right|<1
 $). The second series is similar, note that it can't be start from $0$. If the series are $$x-\sum_{k\geq3}\frac{x^{2k}}{2k\left(2k-1\right)},\,-\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k\left(2k+1\right)}
 $$ you can use a similar argument with the Taylor series of $\log\left(1-x\right)
 $ and $\tanh^{-1}\left(x\right)
 $.

Answer (score 4):

**hint**: $\dfrac{x^{2k}}{2k(2k-1)} = x\dfrac{x^{2k-1}}{2k-1}-\dfrac{x^{2k}}{2k}=x\displaystyle \int_{0}^x t^{2k-2}dt-\displaystyle \int_{0}^xt^{2k-1}dt$

Comment: no idea really. i guess i need to review these urgently. If someone could explain the doings here would really appreciate it :)